# Faster way to multiply all columns in pandas dataframe by itertools combinations

Tags: python, pandas, python-asyncio, combinations, python-itertools

Is there a faster way to multiply all columns in a pandas dataframe with itertools combinations (by any means in python/pandas) by async numba etc

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[312, 345, 875, 907], 
                        [24, 85, 98, 45],
                        [45, 67, 89, 36],
                        [567, 864, 890, 236],],
                  columns=['name', 'age', 'number', 'state'])

import itertools    
for pair in itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2):
    df[new_col] = df[pair[0]] * df[pair[1]]
df
```

Comment: Please post some sample input with expected output for better understanding.

Comment: I think this is the best way to do that

Comment: What is your input and what output do you expect ? Please elaborate

Comment: pandas dataframe - with numbers

Comment: can you please post what you would like your expected ending df to look like?

Comment: I have updated - I hope its clear.. numpy arrays I have tried, but want it to be faster.. any other would be good

Comment: Could you please add numpy solution?